# mysql update values from one column in same table based on another 3 column value

Tags: mysql

I want to set null in value1 if value2, value3, value4 is null where id = 1. If value2, value3, value4 is not null then remain value1/not set null my table looks like:

```
Table: students
id|value1|value2|value3|value4|
-------------------------------
1 |value | NULL | NULL | NULL |
-------------------------------
2 |value | value | NULL | NULL|
```

I want it like this table:

```
Table: students
id|value1|value2|value3|value4|
-------------------------------
1 | Null | NULL | NULL | NULL |
-------------------------------
2 |value | value | NULL | NULL|
```

I try

```
 UPDATE students SET value1 = NULL WHERE students.id = 1 AND value2 = value3 = value4 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should juse several AND is null

```
UPDATE students 
SET value1 = NULL 
WHERE students.id = 1 
AND ( value2 IS NULL AND value3 IS NULL AND value4 IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for one of the following. Depends on what you need.

```
UPDATE students SET value1 = NULL WHERE (value2 IS NULL OR value3 IS NULL OR value4 IS NULL) AND students.id = 1
```

Or

```
UPDATE students SET value1 = NULL WHERE (value2 IS NULL AND value3 IS NULL AND value4 IS NULL) AND students.id = 1
```

Use the first if value1 will be null if any of the others is null, use the second if all the others need to be null before value1 can be null.